# Regularity of measure on a locally compact Hausdorff space with a countable base

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space with a countable base.
Let $\mathcal B$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the family of open sets of $X$. Let $\mathcal M$ be a $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal B$ and $\mu$ a measure defined on $\mathcal M$ such that $\mu(K) \lt \infty$ for every compact set $K$. Such $\mu$ is said to be outer regular if $\mu(E) = inf\{\mu(U): E\subset U, U$ open$\}$ for every $E\in \mathcal M$. And it is said to be inner regular if $\mu(E) = sup\{\mu(K): K \subset E, K$ compact $\}$ for every $E\in \mathcal M$. It is said to be regular if it is both outer and inner regular.

My question is:

> Is $\mu$ regular? If not, what conditions should be added to make it affirmative?

The motivation came from the following observation. Let $\nu$ be the restriction of $\mu$ on $\mathcal B$. Then $\nu$ is regular(See Halmos's *Measure Theory*
). Also note that the Lebesgue measure is regular.

Comment: $\mu$ as you stated is a Radon measure. It defines a bounded linear functional on $C_c(X)$. All (nonnegative) bounded linear functionals on $C_c(X)$ are given by Radon measure. That's Riesz representation theorem.(May need to take completion)

Comment: @John So what is your answer? Is $\mu$ regular?

Comment: It seems that whether or not $\mu$ is regular depends on $\mathcal M$. Now I am not so sure. Not I am not sure even for Lebesque measure: is it true that it has to be regular (with respect to any $\sigma$-algebra containing the Borel subalgebra) whenever it is defined?